# How can we compare the services of different cloud service providers and decide which one is best for us as a company?

Tags: memory, cloud, virtual-machine, storage

For example, my company requires 4 VMs, 2 TB and 256k memory. Which cloud service provider is better for me among AWS, Azure and Google and why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about data location, price, security, network, or what?

If you give no information except some random server specs that even say "256k memory", maybe you should just get a cheap server from Hetzner or other bulk VPS provider.